# Is it possible to cause Click to use -h flag as alias for --h3lp

Tags: python-click

(Stackoverflow doesn't doesn't like the word 'help' in the title)

Click defines automatically the --help. Is it possible to make it also defining -h as an alias for --help?

The closed discussion here https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/2132 says at the end that "... this is what Command.context_settings does". Does it means that context_settings has such an option?